# goroutine not seeing context cancel?

Tags: go, goroutine

I have two goroutines running at the same time.

At some point, I want my program to exit gracefully so I use the `cancel()` func to notify my goroutines that they need to be stopped, but only one of the two receive the message.

here is my main (simplified):

```
ctx := context.Background()
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)

done := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(done, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
wg.Add(2)

go func() {
    err := eng.Watcher(ctx, wg)
    if err != nil {
        cancel()
    }
}()

go func() {
    err := eng.Suspender(ctx, wg)
    if err != nil {
        cancel()
    }
}()

<-done // wait for SIGINT / SIGTERM
log.Print("receive shutdown")
cancel()
wg.Wait()

log.Print("controller exited properly")
```

The Suspender goroutine exist successfully (here is the code):

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "sync"
    "time"

    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/util/retry"
)

func (eng *Engine) Suspender(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup) error {

    contextLogger := eng.logger.WithFields(log.Fields{
        "go-routine": "Suspender",
    })
    contextLogger.Info("starting Suspender goroutine")
    now := time.Now().In(eng.loc)

    for {
        select {
        case n := <-eng.Wl:
            //dostuff


        case <-ctx.Done():
            // The context is over, stop processing results
            contextLogger.Infof("goroutine Suspender canceled by context")
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

and here is the func that is not receiving the context cancellation:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "sync"
    "time"

    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func (eng *Engine) Watcher(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup) error {
    contextLogger := eng.logger.WithFields(log.Fields{
        "go-routine":      "Watcher",
        "uptime-schedule": eng.upTimeSchedule,
    })
    contextLogger.Info("starting Watcher goroutine")

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 30)
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            contextLogger.Infof("goroutine watcher canceled by context")
            log.Printf("toto")
            return nil
        case <-ticker.C:
            
                //dostuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please help me ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Look at a stack trace and see where it’s blocked. If the goroutine is in “do stuff” then it’s not going to see the context cancellation.

Comment: I'm missing the `wg.Done()` calls, otherwise `wg.Wait()` won't receive the context cancel.

Comment: Aside: you can simplify by using [signal.NotifyContext](https://pkg.go.dev/os/signal#NotifyContext)

Comment: @Peter: `signal.NotifyContext` is what I wanted back when I was writing Go 1.13 code (or was it 1.11 or 1.12? anyway, a while ago). Nice to see it got added in 1.16.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try it with an errgroup? It has context cancellation baked in:

```golang
ctx := context.Background()
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
defer cancel()

done := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(done, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

// "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"
wg, ctx := errgroup.WithContext(ctx)

wg.Go(func() error {
    return eng.Watcher(ctx, wg)
})

wg.Go(func() error {
    return eng.Suspender(ctx, wg)
})

wg.Go(func() error {
    defer cancel()
    <-done
    return nil
})

err := wg.Wait()
if err != nil {
    log.Print(err)
}

log.Print("receive shutdown")
log.Print("controller exited properly")
```

Answer (score 0):

On the surface the code looks good.  The only thing I can think is that it's busy in "dostuff". It can be tricky to step through timing related code in the debugger so try adding some logging:

```
  case <-ticker.C:
     log.Println("doing stuff")
     //dostuff
     log.Println("done stuff")
```

(I also assume you are calling `wg.Done()` in your go-routines somewhere though if they are missing that would not be the cause of the problem you describe.)

Answer (score 0):

The code in `Suspender` and in `Watcher` doesn't decrement the waitgroup counter through the `Done()` method call - the reason behind the infinite execution.

And to be honest it's quite normal to forget such small things. That's why as a standard general practice in Go, it is suggested to use `defer` and handle things that are critical (and should be handled inside the function/method ) at the very beginning.

The updated implementation might look like

```golang
func (eng *Engine) Suspender(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup) error {
    defer wg.Done()

// ------------------------------------

func (eng *Engine) Watcher(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup) error {
    defer wg.Done()
    contextLogger := eng.logger.WithFields(log.Fields{
```

Also, another suggestion, looking at the main routine, it is always suggested to pass `context by value` to any go-routine or method calls (lambda) that are being invoked.
This approach saves developers from a lot of program-related bugs that can't be noticed very easily.

```golang
go func(ctx context.Context) {
    err := eng.Watcher(ctx, wg)
    if err != nil {
        cancel()
    }
}(ctx)
```

Edit-1: (the exact solution)

Try passing the context using the value in the go routines as I mentioned earlier. Otherwise, both of the go routine will use a single context (because you are referencing it) and only one `ctx.Done()` will be fired.
By passing `ctx` as a value 2 separate child contexts are created in Go. And while closing parent with cancel() - both children independently fires `ctx.Done()`.

Comment: That's a great idea to use defer to ensure that `wg.Wait` is called.  However, even if it is not called both go-routines will receive the cancel and log a message and exit.  It's only the final `wg.Wait()` that will wait forever (you are right that is a problem).  But my reading was that was not what the OP saw.

Comment: Please refer to my edit-1. It's because the goroutines are accessing the context by reference : )

Comment: Go is a cool language with some small traps, if missed, sometimes debugging is painful. ping @AndrewW.Phillips